# Arrow Function is Not function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an arrow function, but when I call it, indicates that it is not a function.

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

---

```
module.exports = app => {
    const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));
    return {
        send: (config, callback) => {
            if(config.content && config.to && config.subject) {
                let email = {
                    from: 'noreply@fullmonitoramento.com.br',
                    to: config.to,
                    subject: config.subject,
                    text: 'config.subject'
                };
                const path = "./emails/" + config.template + ".html";
                let pageHtml = '';
                fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    pageHtml = data.toString();
                    email.html = pageHtml.replace("[EMAIL.CONTENT]", email.content);

                    mailer.sendMail(email, (err, res) => {
                        if (err) { 
                            console.log("Erro ao enviar email.")
                        }
                        if (typeof callback == "function") {
                            return callback(res);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("Necessário passar um config válido.");
            }
        }
    };
};

mail.send(email, (callback) => {
            console.log(typeof callback);
            // console.log(callback);
        });
```

I'm new with arrow function, perhaps this may be the problem. But I have searched and can not identify the problem.

Comment: what line is the error produced on?

Comment: *minimal* example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @m_callens /home/daniel/Documentos/telemonitoramentonode/api-fullmonitoramento/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
The line is the error will not help, because it comes from nodejs event loop (I think).

Comment: You're specifying "arrow functions" in your question. Are you saying that you get no error with traditional `function` syntax? You have arrow functions all over the place. Which one is causing it?

Comment: At which point do you lose access to 'callback' in the send function?  I suspect it'll be defined at the first line for example, but will no longer be available in the fs.readFile return function.....

Comment: Your variable naming is confusing to me... the `email` parameter is passed as config to `send()`, and the anonymous arrow function as the `callback` parameter. then you call `callback(res)` which means that `res` is the parameter of the anonymous arrow function, which is called `callback`. Did I get that right? In that case `typeof callback == typeof res` (meaning the `callback` when mail.send() is called).

Comment: @squint When I call it the "mail.send (email, (callback) => {"

Comment: @brubdedsbrindeds: So if you delete all the code inside the `main.send()` method, the error still occurs?

Comment: @RobWilson I think that's the problem too, but I can not get around.

Comment: @SimonHänisch Basically, I want the callback to return the result of the send, shown in return callback(res);

Comment: *"Basically, I want the callback to return the result of the send..."* It can't.

Comment: In your question, you have `console.log(typeof callback);`. I'm guessing that in reality you're *calling* `callback`, which obviously will give you the error. There's nothing in your question that shows an issue.

Comment: @squint How do I know the result of my callback then. I honestly do not understand.

Comment: @brubdedsbrindeds: You need to resume the flow of your code's execution at the position where the data response is received. That's the whole point of having a callback in the first place. In other words, the callback you're passing is being invoked, and is passing `res` to it... `callback(res)`, so inside the callback you passed, you can use `res` and do whatever you want with it. You can't however have the `.send()` method return the response. The continuation happens *inside* the callback.

Comment: @squint I removed all return callback and put console.log("success"), yet the error persists. I think the error can is on call: mail.send (email, (callback) => {

Comment: @brubdedsbrindeds: Copy and paste your *exact* code as it is at this moment into http://jsfiddle.net, click the `Save` button, and post the resulting URL here. Or use pastebin or git-gist or something.

Comment: @squint http://pastebin.com/J9AqhzB5 and http://pastebin.com/DKgL3EKk .

Comment: What version of Node are you using? How much code can you delete before the error goes away?

Comment: With that pasted code - are you still seeing the error?  On account of callback not being called in the send method.....

Comment: I just also looked at your code in the pastebins, but it is not clear enough for me how the `mail` object is created. Anyway you should really check the error stack, the first line tells you which file the error occurs in. If it's not in your module, then `callback` could be not related to the `callback` parameter of your `send` function.

Answer (score 1):

Break this into two steps. Define callbalck and then export it.

```
var callback = (app) => {
   // your code
}
module.exports = callback;
```

Or it can be the reason that your environment does not support `ES6`. You need a vanilla ES5 function syntax.

```
module.exports = function(app){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Same erro: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: @brubdedsbrindeds I updated my answer. I think, ES6 is not supported in your environment. Whatever is the case, use simple function, it will work

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz: If arrow functions weren't supported, it would be a SyntaxError, not a TypeError.